# what is the fontsize prefixed with h in gvim

Tags: vim

I am using the gVim7.2 on Windows xp and I have set the gui font as Consolas 11.
using the following code in my .vimrc

> `:set guifont=Consolas:h11`

and all I am curious as to Why is the size prefixed by "h"?
What does "h" mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idigas had it right.

From `:help 'guifont'`:

```
For the Win32 GUI                   *E244* *E245*
- takes these options in the font name:
    hXX - height is XX (points, can be floating-point)
    wXX - width is XX (points, can be floating-point)
    b   - bold
    i   - italic
    u   - underline
    s   - strikeout
    cXX - character set XX.  Valid charsets are: ANSI, ARABIC,
          BALTIC, CHINESEBIG5, DEFAULT, EASTEUROPE, GB2312, GREEK,
          HANGEUL, HEBREW, JOHAB, MAC, OEM, RUSSIAN, SHIFTJIS,
          SYMBOL, THAI, TURKISH, VIETNAMESE ANSI and BALTIC.
          Normally you would use "cDEFAULT".

  Use a ':' to separate the options.
- A '_' can be used in the place of a space, so you don't need to use
  backslashes to escape the spaces.
```